# How to let position:absolute <div> expand, as if it contained a long <p>

Tags: html, css, width, css-position

This `div` expands to contain the `p`. If the paragraph is longer than the page, the paragraph wraps and the div fills the entire width. How can I let the div fill the page in this way without including a paragraph?

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:256px;background-color:blue;">
  <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
</div>
```

Here is a js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qbu0u1s6/2

Comment: Do you mean makin the width 100%?

Comment: Added wider comment in answer

Comment: @TarlanMammadzada Thank you, you're right width:100% works in this case, sorry for simplifying too much! It doesn't work when there are other elements with width:100% inside div, since they become too wide. I added a case of this in the jsfiddle.

Comment: My work-aroudn right now is to put an invisible (white-on-white) long paragraph at the end of the div, but of course I'd like to solve this with CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the width 100% with calc:

```
<div style='width:calc(100% - 100px)'><p>Bla bla</p></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qbu0u1s6/5/

Comment: You're right width:100% works in this case, sorry for simplifying too much! It doesn't work when there are other elements with width:100% inside div, since they become too wide. I added a case of this in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Also, I want "position:absolute;left:256px" because the space to the left is used for other absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: Could you add an image of what you want? width:100% fits entire width.

Comment: Here is a screenshot from my Chrome of the jsfiddle linked in my question: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OfUwf.png , the third div (which contains a width:100% element) is too wide, note the scroll bar. I get the same result with the fiddle you just linked.

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="position:absolute;left:256px;background-color:blue;">
  <p>
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
  </p>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:256px;background-color:blue;word-wrap: wrap-word;">
  <p>
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
  </p>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;top:200px;text-align: center;background-color:blue;width:100%;word-wrap: wrap-word;">
  <p style="width:100%">
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
  </p>
</div>
```

The problem was that, when you set the width as 100% and left as 256px the div will get the 100% of the screen width and starts from left 256px

To prevent it Just change `left:256px;`

And for aligning it to middle use `text-align: center;`

```html
<div style="position:absolute;left:256px;background-color:blue;">
  <p>
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
  </p>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:256px;background-color:blue;word-wrap: wrap-word;">
  <p>
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
  </p>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;top:200px;background-color:blue;left: 256px; width:calc(100%-256px);word-wrap: wrap-word;">
  <p style="width:100%">
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
    bla 0 bla 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla 5 bla 6 bla 7 bla 8 bla 9 
  </p>
</div>
```

And If you still want the `left: 256px` then use `calc()` function in css

It will reduce 256px from the 100% width and give the div the width of the above one

And if you want the text inside the below div to be in center give `text-align: center` to `<p>` tag.

Comment: Hi Advaith, thank you for your answer! I want the 256px to the left of the div to be free, so I can't remove the left:256px. I'm trying to get the same width as the second div in the fiddle, the one where the text wraps, but also for divs that don't contain long paragraphs.

Comment: @ANNA so you want the second div to be in center?

Comment: @Anna I have edited my codes. Please check if this is useful to you or not